# r ggplot2 sequencing date (mm/dd) for x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame where wing length has been registered for a bird over multiple years. I want to plot the wing length as the y-axis and day of the year (mm/dd) as the x-axis.

I have added a column in Excel where mm/dd is extracted from the date and I am running the following code:

```
ggplot(BLACKBIRD, aes(`Day of year`, VIN, group = `Day of year`)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="white", color="black", width= 0.8) +
  ggtitle("Blackbirds DOY") +
  xlab("DOY") +
  ylab("Wing length (mm)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 9)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, color="red", geom = "point") +
  theme(axis.text= element_text(size= 7, angle = 0))
```

My plot is currently very cluttered along the x-axis since all the dates are shown. I want to sequence it so every 10th day is shown along the x-axis.

I know that I need to add something along the line of "scale_x" but I am not sure which one and how I would sequence it.

My last question was closed as there were "similar questions". Let me clarify, the other examples I was provided were of continuous data where the x-axis included data over several years. I want to compile all my years into one and only show how the change is across the year. I have included the plot that I got. I want to sequence the date on the x-axis so that it is not cluttered.

[Image of my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRgIH.png)

I have tried converting "day of year" to date but I recieved the following error:

```
> BLACKBIRD$`Day of year` <- as.Date(BLACKBIRD$`Day of year`)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: Hi @Snooty, it would help if you could share a sample of your data (e.g.`dput(head(BLACKBIRD))`. Anyway, I'd suggest to keep the full date (and not extract mm/dd). Then you can use indeed something like `scale_x_date(labels = dateformat("%m/%d", breaks = "1 week")` - you'll need `library(scales)` for this. And see `?strptime` for all the cryptic date formats .

Comment: In the link I provided in your previous post it is described how "_to create a fake date where a **single year** is concatenated with month and day from the original 'date'._" In both links `scale_x_date` is recommended.